# How to start a list of items as in the same line of the label text in LaTeX format?

Tags: itemize, alignment

I am trying to write the texts of the following image in LaTex format.
[image: goal]

I tried with the following code:

```
\textbf{Input:}
 \begin{itemize}
      \item[] Values of \(x\) over a mini-batch: \(\mathcal{B}=\left\{x_{1 \ldots m}\right\}\);
       \item[] Parameters to be learned: \(\gamma, \beta\)
  \end{itemize}

 \textbf{Output:} \(\left\{y_{i}=\mathrm{BN}_{\gamma, \beta}\left(x_{i}\right)\right\}\)
```

But, I could only get output as shown in the image below:

[image]

Could you please help me how I can align the items to start in the same line as the "Input:" text so that the output will be the same as in the first image?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Why are you using so many instances of `\left` and `\right` directives?

Comment: @Mico thanks. I used those for something, thinking it would work like autolayout constraints in UI development. But it looks not so important here, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could place the `itemize` environment in a top-aligned `minipage`. I would also use a `description` environment to group and organize the "outer" items (Input, Output). That way, you don't need to engage in visual-formatting tedium and, instead, focus on the content of your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item[Inputs]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,left=5pt,label=\textendash]
   \item Values of \(x\) over a mini-batch: \(\mathcal{B}=\{x_{1},\ldots,x_{m}\}\)
   \item Parameters to be learned: \(\gamma\), \(\beta\)
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\item[Output] \(\{y_{i}=\mathrm{BN}_{\gamma, \beta}(x_{i})\}\)

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list for the outer items:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=1.5cm,leftmargin=!]
\item [Input:]
 \begin{trivlist}
      \item Values of \(x\) over a mini-batch: \(\mathcal{B}=\left\{x_{1 
          \ldots m}\right\}\); 
       \item Parameters to be learned: \(\gamma, \beta\)
  \end{trivlist}

\item[Output:]\(\left\{y_{i}=\mathrm{BN}_{\gamma, 
    \beta}\left(x_{i}\right)\right\}\) 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This worked as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the enumitem package:

Note that itemize (any list) will add vertical space, so `Input:` needs to be in an item label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\textbf{Input:}}% measure width
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin={\dimexpr \wd\tempbox+\labelsep}]
  \item[\usebox\tempbox] Values of \(x\) over a mini-batch: \(\mathcal{B}=\left\{x_{1 \ldots m}\right\}\);
  \item[] Parameters to be learned: \(\gamma, \beta\)
\end{itemize}

\noindent\textbf{Output:}\hspace{\labelsep}\(\left\{y_{i}=\mathrm{BN}_{\gamma, \beta}\left(x_{i}\right)\right\}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.